# How should I approach the solution to develope a static, Responsive HTML file that seems to have functionality beyond CSS/HTML capabilities?

Tags: html, css

I have a project that needs a solution that I can't figure out.I don't even know how to approach this:
I have two Photoshop files, each with an initial layout for a Responsive web page design and layers that emulate the intended functionality. I believe the requirement is to find a solution using only HTML with CSS styling. 
"Your task is to deliver a single functional static HTML page."
The first .PSD file was pretty straight forward. However, the second .PSD file changed dramatically with the design layout's overlay. AND, even the fact that there were two drastically different design files seems to be contrary to the instructions to develop a "single" HTML page. 
This is for a potential employer, BTW.

so, the second file has a header section with a logo image and two menu buttons. in vertical succession are two images also positioned in vertical succession. That's all. 
The layer in the file, when made visible (Photoshop) seems to shift the content to the left, changing the menu icon from the "menu" symbol to an "X" symbol and brings into view a black vertical panel with a vertical navigation menu. 
I'm stuck on how to go about making that container shift view with an onclick event hack without scripting. 
i've tried:
1.) using a container div with overflow:hidden = the web page content needs to overlay on that layer and shift with the image...
2.) background image with container over it. = this needs to have the center of the image show only. so, the div on top of the background would need to be opaque around a centralized transparent square. i'm at a loss...

is there some technique or design style that i am missing here?
it seems impossible

this is the psd image file...
http://www.adeninedesign.net/home-320-700.psd

Comment: Use only CSS/HTML to make something that can't be done with CSS/HTML?  Good luck...

Comment: Your question is very dificult to read, consider wording it less like you're talking. I can't view the fiel, but it could be one mobile view and one desktop view from your description. And to me a 'static' website is one that doesn't have a server backend but is statically hosted, so you can probably use JS for the menu and dropdown.

Comment: While I agree with @LcLk about readability, it sounds like you're wanting to employ media queries in the CSS to change the layout and content of the HTML based on it's containter environment. Also add in javascript to handle the `onclick` events. 
A third aspect is to go back to the job and articulate that you are not following what exactly they intend you output with their request -- businesses prefer someone who asks for clarification than someone who chunders into doing a bunch of work on the wrong premise. Good luck

Comment: (I would also highly recommend improving the font choice on your own personal website ;-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Just read about implementing Single Page Applications. Just follow these links.

http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework/

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp

Rest you can always learn from Google about SPA.